# Automatically copy values from cells every week at a set time after their value is changed manually by someone else

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I run a google sheet to track attendance at a kids program I coordinate. Each row features the name, and then several columns of checkboxes to indicate whether they have brought the adequate materials for the program that week. There is a column (PTS TODAY) beside the checkbox columns that will calculate how many pts that child has earned that week based on the boxes they have checked.

So, every Wednesday at 6:30 pm, our check-in person at the desk manually clicks the checkboxes when the kids show up with whatever stuff they have, and by 6:45 all the points for that week are generated.

I would love to learn how to set up the sheet to perform an automated task weekly (Wednesday at 9 pm for example) that will either:
 a) automatically copy the pts column value to an empty column in another sheet
 b) automatically add the pts column value to another column that represents TOTAL PTS earned so far
and also
 c) automatically resets the value of all the checkboxes to zero to reset the attendance sheet.

I have not tried doing any macros, as that is something I am not familiar with.
So far my efforts have included using formulas with an IF statement referencing a cell with a NOW function in order to create some sort of trigger at a certain time each week, but soon realized if that is even a possible tactic that it is beyond my somewhat limited Google-Sheets prowess.

Comment: Welcome. The three things that you mention are fairly simply done. If you want to automate them, then you need to come to grips with understanding how to read and write data using a script. There are many resources on the web, and in the Google documentation ([Reading data and Writing data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#reading_data)). It would be easy for someone to write those scripts for you, but much more beneficial if you yourself understood how and why they work.

Comment: @Kaleb Penner - do you mind sharing the sheet here too? Of course, please redact any personal data.

Comment: Hi, wanted to check if the issue had been solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function thumb(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var count;

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    count = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < data[0].length; j++){
      if (j == data[0].length-1){
        data[i][j] += count;
        break;
      }
      if (data[i][j] == true){
        count++;
        data[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ss.getDataRange().setValues(data);
}
```

I wrote this with a sheet that had a header row that was `names, activities, total`, the activities each had their checkbox button and in the total is where the points went in the end. The code checks which values are true and then adds to the count in the `total` column. In order to get the trigger set up for weekly running you have to follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), you'll be able to specify the day/time when you want it to be run.